# Migrating to JAVA 17 how to get gradle to generate java classes from xsd?

Tags: gradle, xsd, gradle-plugin, java-17, jakarta-migration

I have an application that uses Java-classes that are generated with gradle from xsd-file implemented using JDK 8.
Now we must migrate to JAVA17.
The class-generation no longer works.

A xjc plugin `'org.unbroken-dome.xjc' version '2.0.0'` has been used for this, but this generate javax.xml... instead of jakarta.xml...
Giving `error: package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist`
What should I do to fix this?

The gradle.build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.unbroken-dome.xjc' version '2.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation ....
}

xjc {
    srcDirName = 'resources/xsd'
    extension = true
}
```

I have added to build.gradle

```
    implementation ('jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0')
```

I have found information that the xjb-bindingfile must be updated from

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               jaxb:version="2.1">
```

To

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               jaxb:version="3.0">
```

But when I do that I get ERROR, complaining about the url's beeing wrong

```
> A failure occurred while executing org.unbrokendome.gradle.plugins.xjc.work.xjc23.XjcGeneratorWorkAction
   > Parse failed
```

Have also searched for days for other plugins to use but I cant get them to work, maybe my gradle knowlegde is too poor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of this [gradle plugin](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-xjc-plugin/tree/master) your are using: `'org.unbroken-dome.xjc' version '2.0.0'`, seems possible to use jakarta api instead of java.xml.bind (which [was removed since Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8190378))  configuring the `xjcVersion` property, and using `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0-RC3` dependency instead of jakarta 4.0.0 (because seems that it's not already suported).

```
xjc {
    xjcVersion = '3.0'
}


dependencies {
    // XJC 3.0 requires a different JAXB API artifact
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0-RC3'
}
```

You can see a sample in the plugin source repository: https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-xjc-plugin/blob/master/samples/groovy-dsl/xjc-version-3_0/build.gradle

As additional comment, note that the last version of this plugin is from 2020 and seems that it's not currently in development, if you want to support new jakarta versions maybe you can try with other plugins which are in development and support newer versions for this library: https://github.com/bjornvester/xjc-gradle-plugin

Comment: Thank you bery much! That worked! However I hade to keep the urls from the old-bindingfile.